# Always same issue but almost solved with CSS - space between div in navigation menu

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

From a long time, I get an issue about spaces which are appearing into a navigation menu bar betwwen `<div>` tags of this menu.

This problem only happens on Chrome (currently with Version 59.0.3071.115 (Build officiel) (64 bits) but it was the same with all previous version of Chrome).

Here's the following image illustrating the problem :

[![Space into navigation menu bar][1]][1]

You can also test it directly on the link :

[Link to see White spaces on Chrome][2]

My HTML menu is implemented like this :

```
<div id="nav_bar">
<table class="linkcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/" class="main_link">Home</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/astro/"
class="main_link">Fifo</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/sciences/"
class="main_link">Sciences</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/philo/"
class="main_link">Lifo</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/info/" class="main_link">Exo</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="navigation">
<a href="/FiLo" class="main_link">FiLo</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

with CSS :

```
a.main_link:active, a.main_link:visited, a.main_link:link {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 50px;
}

div.navigation {
    height: 50px;
    width: 133px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table.linkcontainer {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#nav_bar {
    background-image: url(/images_template/header_bg_min.png);
    background-size: 798px 50px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 798px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

As you can see, there are 6 elements `<div>` with `133px` for each of them, that makes `798px` for the total width (see `width` of `#nav_bar` above)

Nevertheless, I have partially found a solution (which is not satisfying) by putting `width: 101%` for `div.navigation` (with `Inspector interface` of Chrome) :

```
div.navigation {
    height: 50px;
    width: 101%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then I get the folowing menu on this image :

[![no more spaces but elements of menu are not centered][3]][3]

As you can see, by putting a `width` value over `100%`, there are no spaces between `<div>` elements but now, they are not horizontally centered anymore like at the beginning of this post.

How could I do to keep this solution (to make disappear white spaces) and, in the same time, keep the horizontal centering of `each <div> element` of the menu ?

Maybe someone would have another solution to circumvent this issue of white spaces with Chrome ?

Regards

Comment: from my understanding, you need the text to be centered and it should be in equal width, right??

Comment: yes but although 6*133 = 798px, white spaces are always present. By setting a value slightly over 100% (in my case 101%) for width, there are no white spaces but then, the text is not horizontally centered any more.

Comment: one more request to you that please highlight your problem in image using red circle and some text over the image.......!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs are wrapped in td elements.

Tables are notorious for having differences between browsers, due to early incompatibilities and inspecific standards.

You are also using tables for layout, which is largely regarded as a bad idea semantically speaking.

I suggest you stop using tables, and instead lay it out using other methods.

I tried to make a jsbin, to recreate your issue. but as stated on your question, and on the site linked, I was unable to reproduce the error.

This is one method of fixing it, without using tables.
https://jsbin.com/pahukezahu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```css
a.main_link:active, a.main_link:visited, a.main_link:link {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 50px;
}
div.linkcontainer{
background:red;
}

div.navigation {
    background:green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 133px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav_bar {
    background-image: url(/images_template/header_bg_min.png);
    background-size: 798px 50px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 798px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="background:black">
<div id="nav_bar">
<div class="linkcontainer" style="width:100%">

<div class="navigation">
<a href="/" class="main_link">Home</a>
</div><div class="navigation">
<a href="/astro/"
class="main_link">Fifo</a>
</div><div class="navigation">
<a href="/sciences/"
class="main_link">Sciences</a>
</div><div class="navigation">
<a href="/philo/"
class="main_link">Lifo</a>
</div><div class="navigation">
<a href="/info/" class="main_link">Exo</a>
</div><div class="navigation">
<a href="/FiLo" class="main_link">FiLo</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that there are no line breaks between the divs, I found that adding linebreaks introduced whitespace.

Comment: It is weird, when I run your code snippet (with Chrome), there are no white spaces on your green navigation bar.

Comment: -@Ryan The Leach I can't reproduce the same menu, div are not horizontally displayed but vertically, could you take a look please on http://beulu.com/test_space/index_modified.html  (with your CSS and HTML modifications) ? Thanks

Comment: You are missing "    display:inline-block;" in div.navigation. I could have made that more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
div.navigation {
  line-height: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting a set width for your nav-boxes 133px, yet spacing them according to a % of the screen width it creates the blank spaces in between the nav-boxes to compensate for the missing space. What you could do, is set the width of each nav-box as a portion of the total width, you have 6 nav-boxes, they could all be `(100/6)%` width hence stretching and shrinking together to fill any screen size. 
In addition to ensure they don't get too small you could add that the width of the individual nav-boxes should never be below 133px.

Comment: I tried for example to set for each box : **width: 134px;** but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

just try adding this to top of you css file.

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: * selectors are generally bad as well, unless it's a global reset, or default font style.

They can affect other components / frameworks you might be using negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a flexbox for the navigation menu.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

a.main_link,
a.main_link:active,
a.main_link:visited,
a.main_link:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}

a.main_link:hover {
  color: red;
}

div.navigation {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 133px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav_bar {
  width: 798px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/" class="main_link">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/astro/" class="main_link">Fifo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/sciences/" class="main_link">Sciences</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/philo/" class="main_link">Lifo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/info/" class="main_link">Exo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/FiLo" class="main_link">FiLo</a>
  </div>
</div>
```